# Solutions of system of PDE's by separation of variables - separation constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I currently have a system of PDE's that are separable. There are two unknown functions $x(r,t)$ and $ y(r,t)$ which can be separated so that $x(r,t)=A(r)B(t)$ and $ y(r,t)=C(r)D(t)$. The system consists of 6 partial differential equations, however, I am confused about the separation constant for the system.

Once separated into ODE's, do we set all ODE's equal to the same separation constant? Or, should we have 6 separated ODE's equal to 6 different separation constants?

Comment: Probably best to be cautious and use a different symbol for each. You can always come back to it when you are happy with the solution process.

Comment: @Paul I thought as much. However, is there advantages/disadvantages in having individual separation constants? When I say individual, I mean individual to each separated equation.  I figure, any possible separable solutions will only differ by a constant which isn't a problem.

Comment: If you have to simultaneously solve the system of equations, then the $x(r,t)$ must be the same in all applicable equations. Same with $y(r,t)$.

Comment: @TrialAndError I know that. But I'm asking about the separation constant

Comment: You're going to have to simultaneously solve the separated equations. Unless the equations in $X$, for example, are all identical, then the separation constants are not likely to be the same. That certainly complicates the process and makes it difficult to imagine everything working out for a system.